# handling "correlated" lines with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

let's say one have a plurality of files in a directory, each file being

File1

```
20100101|12.34|...
20100101|12.34|...
20100101|36.00|...
20100102|36.00|...
20100101|14.00|...
20100101|14.00|...
```

File2

```
20100101|12.34|...
20100101|12.34|...
20100101|36.00|...
20100102|36.00|...
20100101|14.00|...
20100101|14.00|...
```

adjacent lines with same date and value corresponding to the same event.
Two lines in two separate files can't be adjacent.

expected result:

```
e1|20100101|12.34|...
e1|20100101|12.34|...
e2|20100101|36.00|...
e3|20100102|36.00|...
e4|20100101|14.00|...
e4|20100101|14.00|...
e5|20100101|12.34|...
e5|20100101|12.34|...
e6|20100101|36.00|...
e7|20100102|36.00|...
e8|20100101|14.00|...
e8|20100101|14.00|...
```

where eN is here an arbitrary value (e1 <> e2 <> e3 ...) to clarify the sample.

does the following code provide a unique event id for all lines of all files:

```scala
case class Event(
    LineNumber: Long, var EventId: Long,
    Date: String, Value: String //,..
)
val lines = sc.textFile("theDirectory")

val rows = lines.filter(l => !l.startsWith("someString")).zipWithUniqueId
    .map(l => l._2.toString +: l._1.split("""\|""", -1));
var lastValue: Float = 0;
var lastDate: String = "00010101";
var eventId: Long = 0;
var rowDF = rows
    .map(c => { 
        var e = Event(
            c(0).toLong, 0, c(1), c(2) //,...
        );
        if ( e.Date != lastDate || e.Value != lastValue) {
            lastDate = e.Date
            lastValue = e.Value
            eventId = e.LineNumber
        }
        e.EventId = eventId
        e   
    }).toDF();
```

basically I use the unique line number given by `zipWithUniqueId` as a key for a sequence of adjacent lines.

I think my underlying question is: Is there a probabilty that the second map operation split the content of the files accross multiple process ?

Comment: Are files tab delimited?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally no, they are | delimited

Comment: my bad, I meant to ask if it is | delimited. Let me know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idiomatic solution. Hope this helps.  I have used filenames to distinguish files. A groupBy involving file name, zipindex and then join back to original input dataframe resulted in desired output.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


scala> val lines = spark.read.textFile("file:///home/fsdjob/theDir").withColumn("filename", input_file_name())

scala> lines.show(false)
+--------------+------------------------------------+
|value         |filename                            |
+--------------+------------------------------------+
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|
|20100101|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|
|20100102|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|
|20100101|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|
|20100102|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|
+--------------+------------------------------------+

scala> val linesGrpWithUid = lines.groupBy("value", "filename").count.drop("count").rdd.zipWithUniqueId
linesGrpWithUid: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, Long)] = MapPartitionsRDD[135] at zipWithUniqueId at <console>:31

scala> val linesGrpWithIdRdd = linesGrpWithUid.map( x => { org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x._1.get(0),x._1.get(1), x._2) })
linesGrpWithIdRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[136] at map at <console>:31


scala> val schema =
    |   StructType(
    |     StructField("value", StringType, false) ::
    |     StructField("filename", StringType, false) ::
    |     StructField("id", LongType, false) ::
    |     Nil)
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(value,StringType,false), StructField(filename,StringType,false), StructField(id,LongType,false))

scala> val linesGrpWithIdDF = spark.createDataFrame(linesGrpWithIdRdd, schema)
linesGrpWithIdDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, filename: string ... 1 more field]

scala> linesGrpWithIdDF.show(false)
+--------------+------------------------------------+---+
|value         |filename                            |id |
+--------------+------------------------------------+---+
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|3  |
|20100101|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|6  |
|20100102|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|20 |
|20100102|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|30 |
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|36 |
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|56 |
|20100101|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|146|
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|165|
+--------------+------------------------------------+---+


scala> val output = lines.join(linesGrpWithIdDF, Seq("value", "filename"))
output: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, filename: string ... 1 more field]

scala> output.show(false)
+--------------+------------------------------------+---+
|value         |filename                            |id |
+--------------+------------------------------------+---+
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|3  |
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|3  |
|20100101|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|6  |
|20100102|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|20 |
|20100102|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|30 |
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|36 |
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|36 |
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|56 |
|20100101|14.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file2.txt|56 |
|20100101|36.00|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|146|
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|165|
|20100101|12.34|file:///home/fsdjob/theDir/file1.txt|165|
+--------------+------------------------------------+---+
```